# Proof by induction: inequality

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, induction

As the base I was given $\dfrac{4^{n}}{n + 1} < \dfrac{(2n)!}{(n!)^{2}}$ for $n\ge2$

For $n=2$ the inequality is right.

I tried to prove it for $n+1$ and i got here $ \frac{4^{k+1}}{k+2}< \frac{(2k+2)!}{((k+1)!)^2}$. I don't know how to solve it from here.

Someone in the comments referred to me that this question has already been answered and I am very thankful.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you write out the base case? The induction hypothesis step?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far could you get? Where are you stuck? This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question body. Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: When $k=0$ we have equality.